# react-custom-scrollbars safari not rendering

Tags: reactjs, scrollbar

I'm having an issue with `Scrollbars` just in Safari.

App.js

```
import Main from './components/Main';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="app">
        <div className="app-main-container">
            <div style={{position: 'absolute', inset: '0px 0px 0px 0px'}}>
              <div className="app-container">
                <div className="rct-app-content">
                  <div className="app-header">
                  </div>
                  <div className="rct-page">
                    <Main />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

In my Main file I have the Scrollbar

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';

const Main = () => {
    const getScrollBarStyle = () => {
        return {
            height: 'calc(100vh - 50px)'
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Scrollbars
                className="rct-scroll"
                autoHide
                autoHideDuration={100}
                style={getScrollBarStyle()}
            >
                <div className="rct-page-content">
                    <div className="row">
                        <h3>TEST</h3>    
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </Scrollbars>         
        </>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

When I run in Firefox and Chrome, the "TEST" is displayed in the screen, but in Safari it is empty.

Comment: please post your `Scrollbars` component. EDIT: now I see you use `'react-custom-scrollbars'` package. you should note that in your question

Comment: Yes, I added in the code. It's very odd because everything works just fine in all other browsers. Also, no errors are shown in the browser console

Comment: If I go to the browser elements inspection and change the ```rct-scroll``` from ```100%``` to an value in ```px```, it works, but I do not want to have a fixed value